# ZSH Add aliases outside of .zshrc

Tags: alias, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I installed `zsh` on macOS via homebrew and set it as my default shell, along with installing `oh-my-zsh`.

I wanted to add my aliases to a separate file instead of cluttering up my `.zshrc` file.  So I added the following line to the end:

```
. ~/.zsh_aliases
```

However, when I load a new shell, it spits out the error:

```
Last login: Sat Dec 28 00:53:25 on ttys001
/Users/username/.zsh_aliases:97: = not found
```

Even though if I just paste that path into the terminal and hit enter, it runs the file.  The file exists and has `+x` permissions.

Furthermore, it seems that the aliases actually do work.  It just displays the error.

Why am I getting the error?

Comment: What *is* line 97 of `.zsh_aliases`?

Comment: Perhaps you had a space in front of the equal sign in line 97 of `.zsh_aliases`?

Answer (score 0):

Look into `ZSH_CUSTOM` in your `.zshrc`.  set it to a sub-dir of your home-dir such as `omz-custom`

```
# Would you like to use another custom folder than $ZSH/custom?
 ZSH_CUSTOM=~/omz-custom
```

And then put your aliases in it and reload the shell.

```
mv ~/.zsh_aliases ~/omz-custom/alises.zsh && reload
```

Any file with a `.zsh` suffix will get loaded when the shell loads.
I also recommend making your `omz-custom` dir a git repo and pushing it to github.